# How to read XMLTYPE data but namespace in SQL/PLSQL (Oracle)

Tags: xml, oracle

I have this piece of XML data in the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<p:FatturaElettronica xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versione="FPR12">
```

This is the root tag. Now I'm trying to extract data. I'm using xpath as the file is more complex. I was successfully able to read data before namespace using `EXISTSNODE()` and `EXTRACT()` method of XMLTYPE.

Now the root tag is changed. I cannot process the namespace. I was able to process data by defining namespace as:

```
DECLARE
l_ns_def VARCHAR2(240) := 'xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1"';
BEGIN
IF l_xml.EXISTSNODE (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()',l_ns_def) > 0 THEN
l_sender_tic := l_xml.EXTRACT (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()',l_ns_def   ).GETSTRINGVAL ();
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' EOOR - '||SQLERRM);
--END IF;
END;
```

The variables used l_sender_tic is VARCHAR2(2000)
L_COMMON_PATH = /p:FatturaElettronica 
but I cannot extract data now. The error comes as either bind array is too small or ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

I guess the issue is with root tag. The FILE HAS CORRECT syntax that is confirmed. Please help me out on this.

Comment: What are `l_xml`, `l_common_path` and `l_sender_tic`? A more complete example would be helpful. Please see [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: L_Xml is a variable that stores XMLTYPE data

Comment: Find whole example over here.. http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1/IT01234567890_11001.xml

Comment: Do you just need to redefine `l_ns_def` to match what's in that root node's xmlns?

Comment: I'm confused... the full XML you linked to has a different definition to the root node in the question; but matches your PL/SQL code. Please explain what you are showing - does you code work with that links document, but not if the root is changed to what you showed in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work with the XML you linked to:

```
DECLARE
  l_xml xmltype := xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" versione="1.1">
<FatturaElettronicaHeader>
...
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
</p:FatturaElettronica>]');

  l_sender_tic varchar2(4000);
  l_common_path varchar2(30) := '/p:FatturaElettronica/';
  l_ns_def VARCHAR2(240) := 'xmlns:p="http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/sdi/fatturapa/v1.1"';
BEGIN
  IF l_xml.EXISTSNODE (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()',l_ns_def) > 0 THEN
    l_sender_tic := l_xml.EXTRACT (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()',l_ns_def).GETSTRINGVAL ();
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line('Got: ' || l_sender_tic);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' EOOR - '||SQLERRM);
END;
/

Got: 01234567890

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If the root node changes as you've shown at the start of your question then the `l_ns_def` has to change to match:

```
DECLARE
  l_xml xmltype := xmltype(q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versione="FPR12">
<FatturaElettronicaHeader>
...
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
</p:FatturaElettronica>]');

  l_sender_tic varchar2(4000);
  l_common_path varchar2(30) := '/p:FatturaElettronica/';
  l_ns_def VARCHAR2(240) := 'xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2"';
BEGIN
  IF l_xml.EXISTSNODE (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()',l_ns_def) > 0 THEN
    l_sender_tic := l_xml.EXTRACT (l_common_path||'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice/text()', l_ns_def).GETSTRINGVAL ();
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line('Got: ' || l_sender_tic);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' EOOR - '||SQLERRM);
END;
/

Got: 01234567890

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

Very quick example of using [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/query-and-update-XML.html#GUID-4DF303DB-780C-4491-9252-234482A563A4) to extract multiple data points at once; assuming your XML document is in `your_table` in a column called `xml`:

```
select x.*
from your_table t
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2' as "p"),
  '/p:FatturaElettronica'
  passing t.xml
  columns IdPaese varchar2(8) path 'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdPaese',
    IdCodice number path 'FatturaElettronicaHeader/DatiTrasmissione/IdTrasmittente/IdCodice',
    CodiceFiscale number path 'FatturaElettronicaHeader/CessionarioCommittente/DatiAnagrafici/CodiceFiscale',
    Data date path 'FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiGenerali/DatiGeneraliDocumento/Data'
) x;

IDPAESE    IDCODICE CODICEFISCALE DATA       
-------- ---------- ------------- -----------
IT       1234567890    9876543210 18-Dec-2014
```

It can get more complicated depending on the document structure and what you want to extract, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Ok that worked. Is there any other way to read XML files ? I have to store data in relational tables . I used xpath as the XML are complex

Comment: If you're trying to extract various data from an XML document and store it in relational table then [you can use XMLQuery and XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/query-and-update-XML.html#GUID-4DF303DB-780C-4491-9252-234482A563A4). There are quite a few examples around.

Comment: thank you Alex. i was having a hard time finding the solution. thanks for the example.